# Vertx - Simple web server doesn't find the html file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vert.x

I'm trying to write a simple webserver that'd server a html file from the local file system using vertx in java. For some reason the below code doesn't find the file although I have my web/index.html in the resources folder. I'm using IntelliJ and it copies over this folder to the classes folder that it generates for the project. If I give the absolute path it works as expected. What am I doing wrong or how can I figure out whether 'web' folder is a part of the classpath? Btw, I have tested by running this from IntelliJ as well as from the terminal using "mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="test.vertx.VertxDriver" but get the same result - Resource not found.

```
package test.vertx;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.vertx.java.core.*;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServer;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServerRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

public class VertxDriver {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VertxDriver.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VertxDriver driver = new VertxDriver();

        Vertx vertx = VertxFactory.newVertx();
        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
        httpServer.requestHandler(driver.new FileRequestHandler(vertx));

        httpServer.listen(9999,"localhost");

        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class FileRequestHandler implements Handler<HttpServerRequest> {
        private Vertx vertx;

        FileRequestHandler(Vertx vertx) {this.vertx = vertx;}

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServerRequest httpServerRequest) {
            String file = "";
            if(httpServerRequest.path().equals("/")) {
                file = "index.html";
            }
            logger.info("File being served is: "+file);
            httpServerRequest.response().sendFile("web/"+file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And I can't find a 'vertx' tag on stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation to create one.

Answer (score 1):

sendFile doesn't search in the classpath, either you have to put the relative path from target to src or you have to add a maven rule to copy the files over to the target dir.

To figure out where you are actually searching for the files, add `logger.info(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir"));` and check how you can find the correct path.

(This approach has a path traversal security how, BTW)